# Как встроить рабочую функцию в js?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Использую автокоплейт [twitter typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#default-suggestions)

есть там функция в опциях  **minLength: 0**

она отвечает за то, что бы без введения слова, выводился список, при клике на input.

вставить ее в принципе не сложно, смотря на  [пример](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#default-suggestions)

```
  $('.typeahead').typeahead(
  {
  minLength: 0,
},
                null, {
                name: 'stocks',
                displayKey: 'company_name',
                source: stocks.ttAdapter()
            }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
                $('#typeahead').val(data.code);        
            });
```

Но он почему-то не срабатывает!

```js
var stocksData = [
        {
            "company_name": "Facebook",
            "code": "fb",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Google",
            "code": "goog",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Yahoo",
            "code": "yhoo",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Apple",
            "code": "aapl",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Royal Mail",
            "code": "rmg.l",
        },
     ];
    
    var stocks = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: stocksData
        });

        stocks.initialize();

        $('.typeahead').typeahead(
            null, {
            name: 'stocks',
            displayKey: 'company_name',
            source: stocks.ttAdapter()
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
            $('#typeahead').val(data.code);        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="
//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<input class="typeahead" />
<input type="hidden" id="typeahead" />
```

Comment: Мне кажется ошибка заключается в этой строке `<script src="
//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>` добавьте `https:`

Comment: @Insider Это не ошибка. Это называется протоколонезависимые url. Браузер сам решит, что туда подставить - http или https. [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение. Нужно было добавить

```
    var stocksData = [
        {
            "company_name": "Facebook",
            "code": "fb",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Google",
            "code": "goog",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Yahoo",
            "code": "yhoo",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Apple",
            "code": "aapl",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Royal Mail",
            "code": "rmg.l",
        },
     ];

    var stocks = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: stocksData
        });

function getStocks(q, sync) {
  if (q === '') {
    sync(stocks.all());
  } else {
    stocks.search(q, sync);
  }
}

        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            minLength: 0
        }, {
            name: 'stocks',
            displayKey: 'company_name',
            source: getStocks
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
            $('.typeahead').val(data.code);        
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7z9qA/225/